# How to apply Eloquent where() to child in hasMany() relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get the results of this very simple, common `SELECT` statement:

```sql
SELECT * FROM parent
  JOIN child ON parent.id = child.parent_id
  WHERE child.column = 1;
```

For the non-SQL fluent, this returns all of the columns for all parent and child rows where the child column named `column` contains the value 1.

Using the Laravel models below, what's the correct Eloquent way to do this?

```php
<?php
class TheParent extends Model {
    public function child(): HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(Child::class);
    }
}

class Child extends Model {
    public function parent(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(TheParent::class);
    }
}

// Fails.  Returns empty set.
$data = TheParent::getModel()
    ->child()
    ->where('column', 1)
    ->get();    // returns empty set

// Fails:  Returns correct data FOR JUST ONE parent Model if and only if a
// child meets the conditions. But find() is not usable for my purpose.
$data = TheParent::find(1)
    ->child()
    ->where('column', 1)
    ->get();

// Fails:  Only returns the parent data and cannot reference the child.
$data = TheParent::whereHas(
    'child',
    function ($query) {
        $query->where('column', 1);
    }
)->get();
```

Comment: `Child::where('column', 1)->with('parent')->get();`? Or are you wanting it grouped by Parent?

Comment: Grouped by parent would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close with your last attempt; your callback filters the `Parent` instances returned, but not the attached `Child` instances. Try something like this:

```php
$data = TheParent::whereHas('child', fn($q) => $q->where('column', 1))
    ->with(['child' => fn($q) => $q->where('column', 1)])
    ->get();
```

The callback has to be repeated for both the `whereHas` and `with` methods...

- `TheParent::with('child')` returns all parents with all children
- `TheParent::with(['child' => 'some condition'])` returns all parents with some children
- `TheParent::whereHas('child', 'some condition')` returns some parents with all children
- `TheParent::whereHas('child', 'some condition')->with(['child' => 'some condition'])` returns some parents with some children.